# Teams Notification Bot - Cannot run locally (teams app dependencies loop)

Tags: azure, visual-studio, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am trying to debug a teams notification bot locally. Upon building I get the error "There are Teams app dependencies need to be prepared for local debug".

After completing this step and successfully preparing the dependencies, I try to build and run again to just get the same error.

I have tried clearing all the state files, cache, using a new azure account, clearing all entities in azure and bot framework and even creating a brand new project from scratch.

This app used to work fine and debug locally but after revisiting it after a month it no longer does. I have also updated all libraries to their latest versions.

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Edit: Here is the output from preparing the dependencies:

```
Running bot-service concurrently
Creating bot aad app.
Bot aad app creation skipped.
Provisioning bot registration.
Successfully provisioned bot registration.
[Teams Toolkit] Execute Task summary----------------------------
bot-service:provision....................................... [ok]
[Teams Toolkit] Task overall result.........................[ok]
[Teams Toolkit] Provision finished!
Running teams-bot concurrently
Running bot-service concurrently
[Teams Toolkit] Execute Task summary----------------------------
teams-bot:configure......................................... [ok]
bot-service:configure....................................... [ok]
[Teams Toolkit] Task overall result.........................[ok]
[Teams Toolkit] Configuration finished.
Teams app updated REDACTED    
Teams App dependencies are set up, you can click debug or press F5 to continue.
```

Comment: This issue is happened, it might be due to some changes in the Teams platform or the Bot Framework that are not compatible with your current bot code. You might need to update your bot code to match the latest changes in the Teams platform and the Bot Framework.

Also, ensure that you have the latest version of Teams Toolkit and Visual Studio Code.